# php и вывод индекса массива

Tags: php

Есть программа , в которой выводится индекс элемента массива , но почему-то место числа выводится Array . Код:

```
<?php
$first =array(["first", "second"]);
$second =array(["dog", "cat"]);
$all = [];
$all= array_merge($first,$second);
$count = 0;
foreach($all as $i){

    echo "Index $i";
```

Как сделать что бы выводился индекс?

Comment: `foreach` возвращает сам элемент а не ключ. `foreach($all as $key => $i)`

Comment: А вы точно хотите двумерный массив? Если нет, уберите квадратные скобки из объявления массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае `$i` - это не индекс а именно значение, для получения индекса при использовании `foreach`, необходимо использовать конструкцию:

```
foreach($all as $i=>$val){

}
```

где уже `$i` будет выводить индекс.